# custom commands / keyword in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt

This has to be a very simple question... but as long as i can remember i've seen special keywords or commands in the windows command prompt which are clearly not system commands like dir cd etc

Today i was reminded of this using node.js and from the command prompt I cd'd into a director and typed "npm install".

My question is simple... how does the keyword/command "NPM" get associated with a corresponding exe or other "command handler"?  I would think this is very basic but after searching through the internet, its surprisingly hard to find the explanation.

E.g. how could i associate "stack /overflow" with some kind of process/exe that would be able to parse out the "overflow" variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A command line interpreter has a number of built-in functions (your examples of "cd", "dir" etc.). For *all* other input it:

- looks in the *current* folder
- looks in the current PATH folders

to see it finds a matching command with an executable file extension, such as ".exe", ".com", and ".bat". The system wide variable PATH holds a list of folders to search in.

If you write a program called "stack", it will typically be called "stack.exe" in full, and be put wherever your programming environment outputs binaries. Then you can

1. use `cd` to navigate to that folder and type `stack` to call it
2. use the full path specification from any other folder, such as `c:\Users\Documents\MyOwnsoftware\Stack\Release\stack`
3. copy `stack.exe` into one of the folders that is already scanned through the PATH variable
4. add the folder containing `stack.exe` to your PATH.

As you can see, these solutions all comply to the look-up order above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to make CMD recognise "Clear" like from windows PS. great answer!